# Simplifying inequality contradicts actual inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am doing a problem and am not sure why the final step is the following

### $x^{2}<4 <=> -2<x<2$

---

When simplifying
$x^{2}<4$ it becomes $x<±2$ which is the same as $x<2$, $x<-2$

but this does not match the actual inequality of $-2<x<2$, since $x>-2$ not $x<-2$ which is one of the inequalities
obtained in the line above

**My question:**

Inequalities are swapped when multiplying & **dividing by negative numbers**, so is the reason why $x^{2}<4 <=> -2<x<2$

because square rooting both sides of $x^{2} <4$ give $x<2$ AND $x >-2$ since $4$ became $-2$ so it is like the inequality rule of **dividing by a negative number**?
Hence the sign is flipped when considering  $√(4)=-2$? $<=> 4/-2=-2$?

---

### **What I think:**

$x^{2}<4$ gives four possible inequalities:

(1)$x<2$

(2)$-x<-2=>x>2$

(3)$-x<2=>x>-2$

(4)$x<-2$.

By inspection, (1) & (3) are the actual inequalities and (2) & (4) are false solutions.

(1) & (3) = $x<2$, $x>-2$ $<=>$ $-2<x<2$

Is this the reason why??

Comment: Because the real numbers with $x^2<4$ are precisely those between $-2$ and $2$?

Comment: I know one can easily see why $x^{2}<4 <=> -2<x<2$ but I want to know why the simplification does not match this inequality

Comment: You wrote $x<-2$ is a solution but that is wrong. Take for example $x=-3$ then $x^2=9>4$. You must do the flip.

Comment: Yes I know it is wrong. That is a result from simplifying the inequality which gives an incorrect inequality. I want to know why this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct but it is quite tedious to consider the four possible inequalities.

A faster method would be simply observing the fact that,

$$|x|<2$$ where $x^{2}<4$ is true simply when the magnitude of $x$ is less than $2$ (e.g. $x=0,1,1.3,1.999$)

Note that |x| is a piecewise function
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
                -x\\
                 x
                    \end{cases}$$
Therefore, we obtain

- $x<2$
- $-x<2 \Rightarrow x>-2$

$$-2<x<2$$

Also if you were to simplify the inequality using algebra like you have shown in your question, you would have to look through the four inequalities and see which are valid. As mentioned that is tedious, so you should just consider the magnitude of $x$ and make use of $|x|$

Answer (score 3):

Care must be exercised when considering negative square roots. For example, we have $9\gt4$, but not $-3\gt-2$.

So we can only take positive square roots.

From $x^2\lt4$ and $(-x)^2\lt4$ this gives two equations:

- $x\lt2$
- $-x\lt2\implies x\gt-2$

Comment: Wait a second I think thats actually wrong

Comment: $-x<-2==>x>2$ not $x>-2$

Comment: dividing $-1$ on both sides give $x>2$ not $x>-2$ My only guess why the inequality is $x>-2$ is because $√4 = 2,-2$ where $√4=-2 <=> 4/-2=-2$ so inequality sign is flipped. Not sure if this is correct

Comment: Not entirely sure if this matches your answer but I noticed that $x^{2}<4$ gives four possible inequalities: (1)$x<2$, (2)$-x<-2=>x>2$, (3)$-x<2=>x>-2$ (4)$x<-2$. By inspection, (1) & (3) are the actual inequalities and (2) & (4) are false solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with inequalities carefully:

$x^2 < 4 \iff x^2-4<0 \iff(x-2)(x+2)<0 \iff -2< x < 2$

Now can you see why?

Comment: That is still the same as square rooting 4 since solving $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$ individually give the inequalities, respectively $x<2$ and $x<-2$ which still contradicts $-2<x<2$

Comment: Regardless of the approach to this question, does the sign of $x<-2$ get flipped because 4 turning into -2 kind of implies division by a negative number? The result would then be x > -2, which is correct

Comment: No it isn't. Try to figure out what values of $x$ can cause $(x-2)(x+2) < 0$.

Comment: Simply looking at it, the answer would be $-2<x<2$ but simplifying the inequality $(x-2)(x+2)<0$ contradicts $-2<x<2$. Dividing $(x+2)$ on both sides gives the inequality $x<2$ which is correct. But dividing $(x-2)$ on both sides gives the inequality $x<-2$ which contradicts the actual inequality of $x>-2$

Answer (score 0):

You must take care when simplifying the inequality:

You say that $(1):x<2 , (2): x<−2$

Squaring $(2)$:  $x^2>4$. The reason this is, to square $-2$ is to multiply by a negative on the RHS (-2). And on the LHS, you are also multiplying by a negative since $x$ is less than  -2 (hence negative).

Squaring  $(1)$: $x^2<4$.  Well that contradicts $(2)$. So you have made an error.

**Also:** $x<2$ and $x<-2$ implies $x<-2$, and I showed previously that this will imply that $x^2>4$, which contradicts your premise.